# Minor changes produce nan error in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nan

I am a beginner in tensorflow. I have some minor changes in the code of an article but the weights are nan. I posted here the correct code and the modified one. Please help me figure out the problems.
Correct code:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('D:/newcars.csv')
# mileage, cylinder,doors are placeholders for our training data
mileage = tf.placeholder("float")
cylinder = tf.placeholder("float")
doors = tf.placeholder("float")
price = tf.placeholder("float")
a=tf.Variable(1.0)
b=tf.Variable(1.0)
c=tf.Variable(1.0)
d=tf.Variable(1.0)

y_model = tf.multiply(mileage, a) + tf.multiply(cylinder, b) + 
tf.multiply(doors, c) + d
error = tf.square(price - y_model)
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(error)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as session:
session.run(model)
for i in range(len(df)):        
    mileage_value = np.random.rand()
    cylinder_value = np.random.rand()
    doors_value = np.random.rand()
    price_value = 2*mileage_value+ 3*cylinder_value+4*doors_value+1

    print(str(mileage_value) + ' ' + str(cylinder_value) + ' ' + 
    str(doors_value) + ' ' + str(price_value))

    session.run(train_op, feed_dict={mileage: mileage_value, cylinder: 
    cylinder_value,doors:doors_value,price:price_value})
    a_value = session.run(a)
    b_value = session.run(b)
    c_value = session.run(c)
    d_value = session.run(d)
    print(str(a_value)+' ' + str(b_value)+ ' ' + str(c_value) + ' ' + 
    str(d_value))
```

Modified code:
I only replaced

```
mileage_value = np.random.rand()
cylinder_value = np.random.rand()
doors_value = np.random.rand()
price_value = 2*mileage_value+ 3*cylinder_value+4*doors_value+1
```

with:

```
mileage_value = df.loc[i]['Mileage']
cylinder_value = df.loc[i]['Cylinder']
doors_value = df.loc[i]['Doors']
price_value = df.loc[i]['Price']
```

and nan errors occurred although mileage_value, cylinder_value, doors_value and price_value were all correct.

Comment: Are you sure your `df.loc[i]['Category']` values are numbers? Are they not, for example, strings? that would explain your `nan` error.

Comment: Yes, they are all numbers. Their type is int64. I tried to use the code below but still not working: mileage_value =  float(df.loc[i]['Mileage'])
        cylinder_value = float(df.loc[i]['Cylinder'])
        doors_value = float(df.loc[i]['Doors'])
        price_value = float(df.loc[i]['Price'])

Comment: When I debug I saw the weights are updated but I dont know why the print statement displays 'nan' for modified code while it does properly with the original code.

Comment: Finally I figured out the root cause of the problem. It is due to the inappropriate selection of the initial weights and learning rate. In the correct code, these initial values do not affect the results because the magnitude of fluctuations in the input data is small. Therefore, after few first iterations, the weights are updated but till some points these weights are so small and become inf or nan.

Comment: After I normalized the input data, the model can come up with expected results.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the answer to the question yourself. If you feel like it, perhaps add it as an answer to the question so that people who come looking to your question for answers will see what helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the root cause of the problem. The reason is that I did not normalize the input data. Therefore,the magnitude of fluctuations in the input data is huge. As a result, after few first iterations, the weights are updated but till some point these weights are so small or so big and eventually they become inf or nan.
After I normalized the input data, the model can come up with expected results.